# can't get Unity3 and SignalR 2.0 work together

Tags: c#, signalr, unity-container

I try to implement SignalR 2.0 together with Unity3 but so far without success and without exceptions or errors. Also breakpoints doesn't get hit so it is really hard to debug and to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I took this webpage as example: 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection 
but with ninject replaced with unity.

This is my code.

I got a startUp class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Hubs.StartUp))]
namespace Hubs
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var configuration = new HubConfiguration //I put a breakpoint here
            {
                Resolver = GetResolver()
            };

            app.MapSignalR(configuration);
        }

        private static IDependencyResolver GetResolver()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer(); //I put a breakpoint here
            Validations.IoC.Initialize(container);
            return new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
}
```

The UnityDependencyResolver class:

```
namespace Hubs
{
    public class UnityDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType) ?? base.GetServices(serviceType);
        }
    }
}
```

A hub class using constructor dependency injection

```
namespace Hubs.Hubs
{
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ISomeValidation _validation;

        public TestHub(ISomeValidation validation)
        {
            _validation = validation;
        }

        public SomeObject Get()
        {
            return _validation.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Validations.IoC class

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static void Initialize(UnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ISomeValidation, SomeValidation>();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, so can someone help me to figure that out?

Comment: I didn't tend to misuse it. Matter of fact, I still believe I am not misusing it since I tend to use Microsoft Unity (Dependancy resolver/IoC container) and not Unity3d which is, if I google it, used for 3d games. And my issue has nothing to do with games. Maybe you are confused with the version number behind Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I think I might find the cause of the problem. It seems there is a default dependency resolver that tries to resolve the hub class but fails to do it, which makes sense cause I don't register the hub class.

I believe that in the ninject example the registering happens in this code part:

```
kernel.Bind<IHubConnectionContext>().ToMethod(context =>
        resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients
    ).WhenInjectedInto<IStockTicker>();
```

Not sure though as I have never done anything with ninject. I couldn't figure out how to translate this to Unity code.

After some more searching I found another code example here: http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/using-signalr-with-unity/

And that is actually working. It contains also the registering of the hub classtypes and therefor it is probably the solution of my problem.

Comment: This had me stuck for quite some time, as well. I ended up realizing that the IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> that was passed into the StockTicker class was an anti-pattern. The clients are available on the hub, and the StockTicker class should be exposing an event that the hub handles to emit the events to clients.